# Mac Pro bonding interface using layer 3-4 without LACP

Tags: macos, bonding

I need to bond the 2 mac pro ethernet, but using the internal network manager osx only allow LACP as method.

Therefore I need to bond using XOR on layer 3+4 to works on ip level instead of mac address. I have done this on proxmox and works correctly.

It's possible on osx to use XOR balancing on layer 3+4?

Answer (score 1):

No, balance-xor is a Linuxism, not a standard protocol or traditional Unix network stack feature. It is not present in the macOS network stack.